# ctframe not updating ctlines

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Im using core text to display some json text from the web.
The contents are pulled from a nsdictionary that is popuplated to a UITABLEVIEW.

My problem is that the ctframe doesnt want to update the latest content, it keeps redrawing the old text. Ive debugged it and im pretty sure the ctframesettercreateframe is using the latest NSAttributeString

here is my code,
I call this function at every point to display a new text. The markup parser just returns an NSAtributeString

```
- (void)assign_text:(NSString*)text{
self.text = text;


CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable(); //1
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, self.bounds );

MarkupParser *markup = [[MarkupParser alloc]init];
NSAttributedString* attString = [markup attrStringFromMarkup: self.text];


CFAttributedStringRef a = (__bridge_retained CFAttributedStringRef)attString;
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(a); //3

ctFrame =  CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, [attString length]), path, NULL);


CFRelease(a);
CFRelease(path);
CFRelease(framesetter);


}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Flip the coordinate system
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CTFrameDraw((CTFrameRef)ctFrame, context);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you modify your `ctFrame` instance variable, you need to send yourself the `setNeedsDisplay` message:

```
ctFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(...);
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

[Read about the view drawing cycle in the *View Programming Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW10).

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. That View Programming Guide was definitely something Ive never thought of reading.